# Dynamic Bars in an Excel Bar Chart

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

In a typical bar chart, is there a way to dynamically change each bar color based on a variable?  (example: If value is 1 then bar color equal Red, If value is 2 then bar color equal yellow, etc.)

Comment: You might try something along the lines of what's done [here](http://www.k2e.com/tech-update/tips/341-creating-an-excel-chart-with-conditional-formatting).

Comment: What have you researched or tried so far?

Comment: You could try the techniques described here [Conditional Formatting of Excel Charts](http://peltiertech.com/conditional-formatting-of-excel-charts/) or here [VBA Conditional Formatting of Charts by Value](http://peltiertech.com/vba-conditional-formatting-of-charts-by-value/).